# Python: List Equal List or For each in list Append

Tags: python

Would it be OK to use an '=' equal sign while working with the lists? The code below results to a consistent behavior of myOtherList even after myList has been changed. Is there any hidden benefit of using .append() instead of '=' straight equal sign?

```
myList=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
myOtherList=myList    
myThirdList=[]    
for each in myList:
    myThirdList.append(each)
print myOtherList==myThirdList  # True
myList=[]
print myOtherList==myThirdList  # True
```

Comment: The name "mylist" is rebound, to point to a new empty list. The original list hasn't been changed. myOtherList still points to the original list. So yes, this is Ok if this is what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very significant difference between `==` and `is`

Given your example:

```
>>> myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> myOtherList = myList
>>> myOtherList == myList
True
>>> myOtherList is myList
True
```

That indicates that not only do the two lists contain the same values in the same order, they are in fact, the *same* list.  Whereas:

```
>>> myThirdList = []
>>> for each in myList:
        myThirdList.append(each)
>>> myList == myThirdList
True
>>> myList is myThirdList
False
```

They are now two different lists that contain the same values, in the same order.

Comment: Cool, thanks! A good example to see a difference between 'is' and '==' too!

Comment: So far I've been using "if myVariable==None" and "if not myVariable" interchangeably. Do you think it is safer to explicitly define IF statement using "==" equal sign (instead of "is" or "not"?

Comment: @Sputnix It's not safer or less safe, it does what you want or it does something different. They are not interchangable - try setting `myVariable=[]` and then `if not MyVariable: print("hi")` - empty lists evaluate to false, (not false) is true, so it prints. `if myVariable==None: print("hi")` - empty list and None are different, so it stays quiet.